# null an the Display in Flutter but with the right Value in Future

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am pretty new in Flutter and i can not solve this problem.
i have a really simple application. it is just a login with google an a User is created in Firebase, that user have a counter and a button this button increased the counter (int _user.count++).

Then my problem: after the login in the next window, it is not visible the count variable until I click "plus" button. the variable is right and the query with fireStore work great I got the variable but if I do not click the button I got an the display in the place of the variable "null".

Thanks a lot for you Help and Time, I really hope that you can help me. maybe it is a tiny problem I have not found information about it but it is happen when some start to learn.

MyDAO: Hier the Method Future it is the responsable of make the Query to FireStore.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:gauth/user_model.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

final UserDAO userDAO = UserDAO();

class UserDAO {


  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  PublishSubject loading;
  Observable<Future<QuerySnapshot>> profile;

  void updateData(UserModel user) async {
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        _db.collection("users").document(user.uid);
    return documentReference.setData({
      "uid": user.uid,
      "userName": user.name,
      "email": user.email,
      "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
      "count": user.count,
      "lastIn": DateTime.now()
    }, merge: true);
  }

  Future<QuerySnapshot>  readDateFutur(String email) async {
    // loading.add(true);
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await (_db
        .collection("users")
        .where("email", isEqualTo: email)
        .getDocuments());
    // loading.add(false);
    return querySnapshot;
  }

}
```

hier in the method "void initState()" I hold the variable _user.couner, that works.

```
class PlusCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  UserModel user;
  PlusCounter(this.user);
  @override
  _PlusCounterState createState() => _PlusCounterState();
}

class _PlusCounterState extends State<PlusCounter> {
  UserModel _user;
  PublishSubject loading;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _user = widget.user;
      //loading.add(false);

      userDAO.readDateFutur(_user.email).then((QuerySnapshot docs) {
        if (docs.documents.isNotEmpty) {
          print("::::::::::NOESTOY VACIO:::::::::::::::::::::");
          print(docs.documents.last.data["count"]);
          if (docs.documents.last.data["count"] != null) {
            _user.count = docs.documents.last.data["count"];
          } else {
            _user.count = 0;
          }
        } else {
          print(":::::::::::ESTOY VACIO:::::::::::::::::");
          _user.count = 0;
        }
      });

    });
  }

  void _plus() {
    setState(() {
      _user.count++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Cuantas veces te has \n lavado las manos:"),
        Text("${_user.count}"),
        MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _plus();
          },
          child: Text("Plus"),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () => userDAO.updateData(_user),
          child: Text("Guardar"),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

WelcomePage code is this one.

```
class userDataWelcome extends StatelessWidget {
  UserModel _userModel;

  userDataWelcome(this._userModel);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Welcome"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(_userModel.photoUrl),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text("${_userModel.name}"),
            PlusCounter(_userModel),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () => authService.SingOut(),
              child: Text("Logout"),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then I really do not why I need to click "plus" button before I can see the Value of _user.count, because I just see null in otherwise. just again I want to say Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping this line in `initStat()` `_user.count = docs.documents.last.data["count"];` in `setState((){});` like this

```
setState((){
_user.count = docs.documents.last.data["count"];
)};
```